# TimeLinePlot: change the y-axes ranges

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

I want to combine a `TimeLinePlot` with a `DateListPlot`. My questions are:

1. Can you change the Y-axes of a `TimeLinePlot`?
2. Can you visualise the Y-axes of the `DatelistPlot` if you combine both plots using the `Show` function?

I use the next datasets:

```
data1e = {{DateObject[{2017, 01, 01}], 
     "event1"}, {DateObject[{2017, 01, 02}], 
     "event2"}, {DateObject[{2017, 01, 03}], 
     "event3"}, {DateObject[{2017, 01, 04}], 
     "event4"}, {DateObject[{2017, 01, 05}], 
     "event5"}, {DateObject[{2017, 01, 06}], 
     "event6"}, {DateObject[{2017, 01, 07}], "event7"}};
 data1d = {{DateObject[{2017, 01, 01}], 
    1}, {DateObject[{2017, 01, 02}], 2}, {DateObject[{2017, 01, 03}], 
    3}, {DateObject[{2017, 01, 04}], 4}, DateObject[{2017, 01, 05}], 
   5}, {DateObject[{2017, 01, 06}], 6}, {DateObject[{2017, 01, 07}], 
  7}}; data2e = {{DateObject[{2017, 01, 08}], 
   "event1"}, {DateObject[{2017, 01, 09}], 
   "event2"}, {DateObject[{2017, 01, 10}], 
   "event3"}, {DateObject[{2017, 01, 10}], 
   "event4"}, {DateObject[{2017, 01, 10}], 
   "event5"}, {DateObject[{2017, 01, 10}], 
   "event6"}, {DateObject[{2017, 01, 10}], 
   "event7"}, {DateObject[{2017, 01, 11}], 
   "event8"}, {DateObject[{2017, 01, 12}], 
   "event9"}, {DateObject[{2017, 01, 13}], 
   "event10"}, {DateObject[{2017, 01, 14}], "event11"}};
data2d = {{DateObject[{2017, 01, 08}], 
    110}, {DateObject[{2017, 01, 09}], 
    120}, {DateObject[{2017, 01, 10}], 
    130}, {DateObject[{2017, 01, 11}], 
    140}, {DateObject[{2017, 01, 12}], 
    150}, {DateObject[{2017, 01, 13}], 
    160}, {DateObject[{2017, 01, 14}], 170}};
```

I write 4 scripts to generate the different graphs.

```
TLP1 = TimelinePlot[
  MapThread[Labeled, {data1e[[All, 1]], data1e[[All, 2]]}]
  , PlotTheme -> "Detailed"
  , ImageSize -> 500
  , PlotRange -> {{DateObject[{2017, 01, 01}], 
     DateObject[{2017, 01, 14}]}, Automatic}];

DLP1 = DateListPlot[data1d
  , PlotTheme -> "Detailed"
  , ImageSize -> 500
  , PlotRange -> {{DateObject[{2017, 01, 01}], 
     DateObject[{2017, 01, 14}]}, {0, 200}}];

Show[{TLP1, DLP1}]
```

[image]

```
TLP2 = TimelinePlot[
  MapThread[Labeled, {data2e[[All, 1]], data2e[[All, 2]]}]
  , PlotTheme -> "Detailed"
  , ImageSize -> 500
  , PlotRange -> {{DateObject[{2017, 01, 01}], 
     DateObject[{2017, 01, 14}]}, {0, 200}}];

DLP2 = DateListPlot[data2d,
  , PlotTheme -> "Detailed"
  , ImageSize -> 500
  , PlotRange -> {{DateObject[{2017, 01, 01}], 
     DateObject[{2017, 01, 14}]}, {0, 200}}];

Show[{TLP2, DLP2}]
```

[image]

Both graphics has different sizes. Becasue I want to combine them in a (powerpoint) presentation I would like to have them the same sizes. And I want to show the the X-axes and the Y-axes.

Anyone a suggestion how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** For versions 11.3 and 12.2 we can use the following two functions to post-process the `TimeLinePlot` output to modify the vertical scale:

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"
> ```

```
ClearAll[modifyScaleV11]
modifyScaleV11[g1_, g2_] := MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, 
    RescalingTransform @@ (PlotRange /@ {g1, g2})] &, g1, {1}]

Show[DLP2, modifyScaleV11[TLP2, DLP2]]
```

[image]

```
$Version (* Wolfram Cloud *)
```

> ```
> "12.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (November 16, 2020)"
> ```

```
ClearAll[modifyScaleV12]
 
modifyScaleV12[g1_, g2_] := Module[{pr = {PlotRange[g1][[1]], 
    {0, 1 + Max@Cases[g1, Inset[_, Offset[_, {_, a_}], ___] :> a,  All]}}},
  MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, RescalingTransform[pr, PlotRange[g2]]] &, g1, {1}]]

Show[DLP2, modifyScaleV12[TLP2, DLP2]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

You  can modify the output of `TimeLinePlot` by rescaling the y-coordinates of the graphics primitives in it.

The function `scaleF[g1, g2]` below creates a scaling function that rescales any number in the vertical `PlotRange` of `g1` to the vertical `PlotRange` of `g2`. The function `modifyF[g1, g2]` replaces the graphics primitives in `g1` with their rescaled versions.

```
ClearAll[scaleF, modifyF]
scaleF[g1_, g2_] := Rescale[#, ## & @@ (PlotRange[#][[2]] & /@ {g1, g2})] &;

modifyF[g1_, g2_] := g1 /. {(head : Alternatives[Polygon, Point, Line])[x__] :> 
 head[x /. {Offset[y_, {a_, b_}] :> Offset[y, {a, scaleF[g1, g2]@b}], 
  {c_, d_} :> {c, scaleF[g1, g2]@d}} ], 
Inset[ins_, pos_, rest___] :> Inset[ins, pos /. Offset[y_, {a_, b_}] :> 
  Offset[y, {a, scaleF[g1, g2]@b}], rest ]};
```

***Example:***

```
Show[DLP2, modifyF[TLP2, DLP2]]
```

[image]

Comment: Your answers are always very useful. I recently made a [package](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/Misc/HeatmapPlot.m) that utilizes [one of your MSE answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2559/34008) for making heat-map plots.

Comment: Thank you @Anton. Playing with your package now.

Comment: I have to say it does not always work as expected. I have to re-write the `MatrixPlot` parts.

Comment: Hi @kglr, did youn changed something in your answare?. When I use your code I get not the same result.

Comment: @MichielvanMens, I have not made any changes in the code. Please note that, in version 11`,  for  `PlotRange[g]` to work   explicit values need to  be set in `g` for the option `PlotRange`.

Comment: Hi @kglr The first time I used your code, it works fine. Until yesterday, When I tried your code again, the code didn't give the same result. So I tried your code in de Wolfram-develoment environment and it's works fine. I don't understand this. Do you?

Comment: @Michiel, I am using wolfram-development environment; i don't have acces to desktop v11.

Comment: @kglr, Until MMA 12.0 your solutions worked fine. Now I upgraded to 12.2 and wanted to re-use your code. In version 12.2 it doesn't work any more. Do you know why? My question is because i do not understand your code but I want to use it.

Comment: @MichielvanMens, please see the update.